# R Shiny detect saved data event

Tags: r, shiny

I am using sqlSave() to save data to the database.
Once the save is successful, I would like to somehow trigger an event so that the front end UI can update display showing total number of rows in the db.

In Server.R, I have:

```
#ui showing database info
output$dbstatus <- renderUI({
HTML(displayDBStatus()) #reads from database and builds ui.
})

#saves data to db:
observeEvent(input$saveButton, {
mySaveFunc() #writes to db using sqlSave
})
```

How do I get `output$dbstatus` to refresh once the sqlSave has completed successfully? How do I create an event from a successful save operation so that I can build a reactive function against it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see, for what you wrote, there is no reason to have a `renderUI`, since the expression inside it doesn't depend on any input. Put the input dependency on it and call `mySaveFunc()` inside it:

```
 output$dbstatus <- renderUI({
    #trigger the event when the button is pressed
    input$saveButton
    #save the values on the db
    mySaveFunc()
    #display the element
    HTML(displayDBStatus()) #reads from database and builds ui.
 })
```

In this way you don't need the `observeEvent` part.

Comment: Actually renderUI already has a dependency; I was just trying to simplify the example :-). Regardless, your solution gets me back on the right track - thank you. The only problem now is that renderUI evaluates its dependencies all the time, so input$saveButton is evaluated regardless of whether it is clicked or not...